# Magento CE 1.9.1.1 database connect error during install

Tags: magento-1.9

CE 1.9.1.1: Without a shadow of a doubt the db and dbu credentials are correct. I see an article on the subject here: http://www.appseconnect.com/magento-community-1-9-fresh-installation-problems-and-solutions/ |but I'm not confident in my ability to interpret these instructions.

Can anyone tell me specifically how to get around this apparent Innodb requirement? I'm installing on a live server / new site so I wonder if I can ftp to the correct files or access via cPanel. I am not skilled in ssh.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help greatly if you would include the exact error language you are getting.

Comment: Exact language is: "database connect error". I ended up paying someone fix the issue for me so unfortunately I cannot report the solution.